# Twilio Speech Gather not working as I expected. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, twilio

Using Node.js I've managed to get DMTF working pretty well, but now I have to actually gather voice and it's not working as I expected, so I'm obviously doing something wrong.  Here are my two functions:

```
exports.testSpeech = functions.https.onRequest(async(req,res)=>{
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse()
  const gather = twiml.gather({
    'voice':'alice',
    'language':'en-US',
    'input':'dmtf speech',
    'finishOnKey':'#',
    'speechTimeout':15,
    'speechModel':'phone_call',
    'action':'testSpeechResults'
  })
  gather.say('Hi. tell me something I don\'t know.')
  console.log(twiml.toString())
  res.status(200).send(twiml.toString())
  return null
})
exports.testSpeechResults = functions.https.onRequest(async(req,res)=>{
  console.log('This is my response:',JSON.stringify(req.body))
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse()
  twiml.say({
    'voice':'alice',
    'language':'en-US'
  },'Sorry, I alrady knew that. Goodbye')
  twiml.hangup()
  res.status(200).send(twiml.toString())
  return null
})
exports.twilioStatusChange = functions.https.onRequest(async(req,res)=>{
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
  const from_phone = TEST_PHONE !== '' ? TEST_PHONE : req.body.From
  console.log('twilioStatusChange',from_phone)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
  res.status(200).send({})
})
```

My log shows that testSPeech is hit but after I say something and press the # key I'm dumped into my twilioStatusChange webhook, not the testSpeechResults webhook I'm expecting. Here is the output of twiml.toString at the end of the testSpeech function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Gather voice="alice" language="en-US" input="dmtf speech" finishOnKey="#" speechTimeout="15" speechModel="phone_call" action="testSpeechResults"><Say>Hi. tell me something I don't know.</Say></Gather></Response>
```

There are no errors logged.

Answer (score 0):

Gather was not the correct verb I needed.  To do what I expected required Record

Comment: I'm glad you have sorted this. `<Record>` allows you to record messages from a user whereas `<Gather>` allows you to do live speech to text. When using `<Gather>` with speech you should look for the `SpeechResult` parameter in the request parameters to your action URL. Let me know if you need any further help.